# Cropping WebViews in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-webview, android-xml

I have a WebView that loads the web page using the standard invocation.

The `Kotlin` code I used-

```kotlin
myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

val projectUrl: String = "Web page URL"
myWebView.loadUrl(projectUrl)
```

With this, I am able to see my web page well, what I want to do is crop the webpage something like not showing the top 20 pixels or bottom 20 pixels of my loaded web page. How could I do this?

I would give more preference to an authentic solution but I am also fine in implementing a hack for this.

Comment: Once your web view is loaded, You can take screenshots of your screen programmatically and then crop your image leaving some margin from the top.This margin will be sum of Status Bar and App Bar. You can calculate the height of these two programmatically.

Comment: @HritikGupta That would definitely be a computationally expensive solution

Answer (score 1):

I would ask for more detail why you would ever want to do something like this? Sounds like an issue that should be sorted on the webpage design side.

Hack:
Could I suggest you just place two opaque views over the top of your webview and then programatically set the transparency/height to your preference?

Comment: I agree this is definitely an issue on the design side, I am trying to just make it work and did not need it to be scalable or stuff. So this does the work for now! However, I will just wait a couple of days before marking this accepted if I could get any legacy solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used the `marginTop` as you can see here and set it to `-150dp` so it will crop the `webview` above:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="-150dp" />
```

You will see something like this on your design, it's like having an invisible imageline:

[image: Design margin indicator]

Once the app reloads you may now not see the croped area and not allowed to scrolled on that particular area.

Comment: Perfect answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the app and log the scroll y-pos to decide the desired area you want the user to scroll between and if the user exceeds this area **back him back**
so in this example from 0 to 135 it's not desired header for me to show so I prevent the user from scrolling in y-pos lower than 135
and after 6600 and don`t want the user to see the content so I do the same process

```
// first scroll to hide the header
    webView.scrollTo(0 , 135);
// listen for the user scroll to prevent him from scrolling on a hidden area
    webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                    if(scrollY<135) webView.scrollTo(scrollX , 135);
                    if(scrollY>6600) webView.scrollTo(scrollX , 6600);
                }
            });
```